# Xcode 4 / Git - backup

Tags: xcode, git, backup

What is the most simple way to backup my project? Can I just copy XCode project (with hidden .git) directory to USB stick and copy it back when needed?

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine, but it is rather inefficient. I've done it with timecapsule and this just works.

You can also create a "bare" repository on the stick and regular push your work to it.

This is a lot smaller than the original, but you will not have all your branches (unless you all push them of course).

If you have a second computer then you can push/fetch the project back and forth, and you always have 2 copies. If you fetch from the remote PC you get all the branches.

Sites like github and gitorious allow you to push your repository to the cloud and also serve very effectively as a backup.

This is what is great about distributed version control : so much flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is tracked with git. You can backup the git repo with [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy).

```
git copy /path/to/project /Volumes/usb/project.backup
```

Then you can restore your project with `git clone`

```
git clone /Volumes/usb/project.backup project
```